# How to find the solution of $\frac{d^2 y}{d x^2}=\alpha e^{\lambda x} y^n$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm interested in the solution of $\frac{d^2 y}{d x^2}=\alpha e^{\lambda x} y^n$ with initial data $y(0), y^\prime(0)$, where $\alpha,\ \lambda$ are constant, and $n \geq 0$ is a interger. How to find the solution of this equation? Or find the approximate solution.

Comment: Would Wolframalpha suffice?

Comment: So what's the problem exactly ?

Comment: You could represent it : $\frac{d^{2}{y}}{{y^{n}}} = \alpha e^{\lambda x} d^{2} x$

Comment: @openspace just want to solve the equation of motion in such potential.

Comment: @openspace second order derivative cannot be operated like this

Comment: @S.Klumpers I have used mathematica but it can't solve this equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this transformation](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0313.pdf) to reduce the problem to the first order ODE
\begin{equation}
 (\lambda + (n-1) w) z \frac{\text{d} w}{\text{d} z} = \alpha z - w^2.
\end{equation}
This is an Abel differential equation of the second kind. You can use [this transformation](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0126.pdf) to bring it to canonical form. General solutions for this equation are not known, but for special cases, you might be lucky: see [here](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0124.pdf) for solvable cases.

In general, it is worthwhile to check out [EQWorld](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/index.htm) for this type of problems.

Answer (score 0):

As you also look for an approximate solution, you can try numerical calculations,

Whence you prove there exist a solution;

$u = y(x)$

$v = y'(x)$

And setting $W = [u,v]^T$, you will have $W'(x) = F(x,W)$ with the initial condition $W(0) = [y(0), y'(0)]^T$ where you can apply numerical first order ODE solution methods. (backward/forward euler methods, runge kutta's, etc...)

Comment: Certainly, it can be solved by numerical methods. If I set $\alpha, \lambda, n$ and initial data, I can use mathematica to solve it directly with numerical methods. But I cannot see the relationship with these parameters.